# Disable test condition if the previous one succeeded

Tags: c++, c++11, metaprogramming, template-meta-programming

I have the following code:

```
struct has_to_string    {};
struct has_error_string {};

template<typename T>
struct checker
{
    template<typename, typename> struct checker_helper;

    template<typename C>
    static has_to_string    test(checker_helper<C, decltype(&C::toString)> *);
    template<typename C> // Enable this test only if the previous one has failed
    static has_error_string test(checker_helper<C, decltype(&C::errorString)> *);
    template<typename C>
    static std::false_type  test(...);

    using type = decltype(test<T>(nullptr));
};

template<typename T>
using checker_t = typename checker<T>::type;

template<typename T1, typename T2, typename R>
using enable_if_same = typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T1, T2>::value, R>::type;

template<typename T, typename C>
inline enable_if_same<std::false_type,  C, QString> _moduloHelper(const QString & s, const T & value)
{ return s.arg(value); }

template<typename T, typename C>
inline enable_if_same<has_to_string,    C, QString> _moduloHelper(const QString & s, const T & value)
{ return s.arg(value.toString()); }

template<typename T, typename C>
inline enable_if_same<has_error_string, C, QString> _moduloHelper(const QString & s, const T & value)
{ return s.arg(value.errorString()); }
```

This code allows me to call a specific function (in this case `toString` or `errorString`) if the template parameter have this function. And this works perfectly. The only problem that I have is when I use this function with a class that have both `errorString` and `toString` function.

In this case the program does not compile any more due to the ambiguous call of the `checker::test` function. I completely understand why the code does not compile but if this case append I would like to choose the `toString` version every time but I don't know how to do that.

BTW this is how to call the `_moduloHelper`:

```
int main()
{
    QString str("%1");
    _moduloHelper<QUrl, checker_t<QUrl>>(str, QUrl());
}
```

Of course I have a wrapper around this but this is not the point here.

Comment: Use two separate sets of functions, under different names - one checking for `toString` and the other for `errorString`. Then make a logical combination of the two tests as you see fit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would offer my solution it is not so minimalistic as you initial might be. Sometimes in C++ template metaprogramming code grows very fast. However, my solution, besides solving your problem, has another advantage - it checks the return type of the functions. You might consider using preprocessor to reduce the code redundancy.

```
template <typename T>
struct to_string_checker {
  template <typename C,
            typename
            = typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<decltype(std::declval<C>().toString()),
                                                   QString>::value,
                                      void>::type>
  static std::true_type test(int*);
  template <typename C>
  static std::false_type test(...);

  constexpr static bool value = decltype(test<T>(nullptr))::value;
};

template <typename T>
struct to_error_string_checker {
  template <
    typename C,
    typename = typename std::
      enable_if<std::is_same<decltype(std::declval<C>().errorString()), QString>::value,
                void>::type>
  static std::true_type test(int*);
  template <typename C>
  static std::false_type test(...);

  constexpr static bool value = decltype(test<T>(nullptr))::value;
};

template <typename T>
typename std::enable_if<to_string_checker<T>::value, QString>::type
_moduloHelper(const QString& s, const T& value) {
  return s.arg(value.toString());
}

template <typename T>
typename std::enable_if<(!to_string_checker<T>::value
                         && to_error_string_checker<T>::value),
                        QString>::type
_moduloHelper(const QString& s, const T& value) {
  return s.arg(value.errorString());
}

template <typename T>
typename std::enable_if<(!to_string_checker<T>::value
                         && !to_error_string_checker<T>::value),
                        QString>::type
_moduloHelper(const QString& s, const T& value) {
  return s.arg(value);
}

int main() {
  QString str("%1");
  _moduloHelper(str, QUrl());
  QString str2("%1");
  _moduloHelper(str, 10).toStdString();
}
```

Comment: Your solution is great but is does not works with a type that should use the first version of `_moduloHelper` (e.g. a  `int`)